# List out of range in python?

Tags: python, list

i am trying to pick 7 numbers at random out of a list on 10, i have written the following code to help me do that :

```
s=set(range(1,10))
import random


i = []
while len(i)<8:
  s.remove(random.choice(list(s)))
  i.append(s)

print i
```

an important point of this is the number is removed from the group to prevent it being picked twice

however when i run the code i get the error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "randomTest.py", line 7, in <module>
    s.remove(random.choice(list(s)))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/random.py", line 273, in choice
    return seq[int(self.random() * len(seq))]  # raises IndexError if seq is empty
IndexError: list index out of range
```

What is causing the error and how do i fix it ?

Comment: Wouldn't you just do `np.random.choice(s, 7)` where `s` is an array?

Comment: Look at the comment: ```# raises IndexError if seq is empty```. Maybe your list is empty?

Comment: the code as posted does not produce an error

Comment: I can't reproduce your error, but there are a few problems with your code beside. For one, you probably don't want to append the whole sequence `s` to `i`

Answer (score 4):

Don't reinvent the wheel. What you are looking for is [`random.sample`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.sample) -

```
>>> s=set(range(1,10))
>>> import random
>>> random.sample(s,7)
[7, 5, 6, 8, 9, 3, 4]
```

Though this working on `set` actually seems like an implementation detail (and may not work for sets with more than 21 elements) because `random.sample` internally converts the iterable (first argument) it receives into a list at https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/c6880edaf6f3/Lib/random.py#l330. It would be better to not rely on this implementation detail and manually convert the set/sequence to a list or sequence -

```
>>> s=set(range(1,10))
>>> import random
>>> random.sample(list(s),7)
[6, 8, 4, 2, 5, 9, 7]
```

From documentation -

> `random.sample(population, k)`
>
> Return a k length list of unique elements chosen from the population sequence. Used for random sampling without replacement.

And as mentioned in the comments, you may not really need a set here.

Comment: I don't think you need the `set` -- Actually, I'm _really_ surprised that it works with a set since sets aren't sequences and other random functions (like `choice`) actually enforce it... (`isinstance(set(), collections.Sequence) == False`)

Comment: Yea, I just left it there since the OP had it, maybe his actual data is in the form of set or so.

Comment: Because `random.sample()` itself converts its population (first argument) into a list - https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/c6880edaf6f3/Lib/random.py#l330 . It seems like an implementation detail to me, I added that part to the answer as well , would be better to not rely on that.

Answer (score 0):

You code should not produce `IndexError: list index out of range`, since in your example `s` contains 10 elements, and you choose 7.
Maybe this exception was raised while executing this code on a different set.

However, you should fix a bug that will prevent you from seeing the results you seek:

Each time, you are appending all of `s` into `i`, what you want is to append only the chosen value.

Suggestion:

```
s=set(range(1,10))
import random

i = []
while len(i)<8:
  chosen = random.choice(list(s))
  s.remove(chosen)
  i.append(chosen)

print i
```